# Using Containable with forced joins

Tags: php, cakephp

Here's my associations:

- Favorite belongsTo Album
- Album belongsTo Artist
- Artist HABTM Section

Basically what I am trying to do is use the containable behavior with forced joins. If a user is looking at all his favorites, I want to contain the album associated with the favorite, the artist associated with that album, and the sections the artist belongs to. This would be easy enough to do with the containable behavior like so:

```
$this->Favorite->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Album' => array(
            'Artist' => array(
                'Section'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

My problem is that I also want the user to be able to search by artist AND album name. Unfortunately I can't just do this:

```
$this->Favorite->find('all', array(
    ...
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Artist.name LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->query['query'] . '%',
            'Album.name LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->query['query'] . '%'
        )
    )
));
```

Why? Because Cake will only perform the first join to `Album` and it will do a separate query for the artist. So what I've had to do instead is remove the containable behavior, and do the joins manually so that I can search by both artist and album name like so:

```
$this->Favorite->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Favorite.*',
        'Album.*',
        'Artist.*'
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            'Artist.name LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->query['query'] . '%',
            'Album.name LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->query['query'] . '%'
        )
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'albums',
            'alias' => 'Album',
            'type' => 'left',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Album.id = Favorite.album_id')
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'artists',
            'alias' => 'Artist',
            'type' => 'left',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions' => array('Artist.id = Album.artist_id')
        )
    )
));
```

This works great for being able to search by artist and album name. My problem is that I also want to contain the sections that an artist belongs to. I can't just add the `contain` key back in because Cake will duplicate the `Album` join which will throw a 'not unique table alias' error.

My question is, what is the best or most efficient way to get the sections associated with each artist without having to loop through each favorite and perform a separate query for each? Or is this the route I'm going to have to take?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I've managed to get this figured out with a (dirty) hack:

```
$this->Favorite->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Album' => array(
            'Artist' => array(
                'Section'
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            '(SELECT name FROM artists WHERE id = Album.artist_id) LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->query['query'] . '%',
            'Album.name LIKE' => '%' . $this->request->query['query'] . '%'
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant mix and match `containable` with `joins` so you need to do something slightly different.

Create some additional relations on the fly with [bindModel](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-bindmodel-to-get-to-deep-relations) and then you can use the new relations for conditions while using the standard relations for containable.